# How to make these forms responsive?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to create a mobile friendly site of this [SITE](http://goo.gl/mtSFzM).
The mobile site will be loaded only on mobiles and tablets.

After spending couple of days I could be able manage the responsive (mobile only) site like this: [RESPONSIVE MOBILE ONLY SITE](http://goo.gl/Ru0iHw)

Now I have issues with forms only which are placed at the bottom.
All three forms are in these classes `.home_forms_res`,  `.home_forms2_res`, `.home_forms3_res` need to be responsive.

I've tried several ways but could not make it responsive.
My CSS codes are in `responsive.css` file.

How can I make these three forms responsive?

Comment: you've been here for a while. You should know to post your code when asking a question

Comment: yeah @RachelGallen but the code is so lengthy.. that's why I avoid posting code and gave the page link.. sorry..

Answer (score 0):

To make those three forms responsive, you need to use percentage based widths instead of fixed pixel widths.
This will allow the html elements to resize fluidly compared to the width of the browser window or parent element.